# ldapsearch with username and password

Tags: ldap, ubuntu-14.04, openldap

Here is my LDAP ORG Structure:

[image: LDAP ORG Structure]

I created user with first, last name with password. But it is not working when am trying to connect using jdbc. Error says invalid credentials. Then I tried ldapsearch as follows:

I followed this [process](https://www.linuxsecrets.com/blog/3security-and-authentication/2015/07/02/1550-complete-guide-installing-openldap-and-phpldapadmin) for users and group creation:

```
root@ip:/home# ldapwhoami
SASL/DIGEST-MD5 authentication started
Please enter your password:
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Invalid credentials (49)
    additional info: SASL(-13): user not found: no secret in database

root@ip:/# ldapsearch -x -LLL -h ip -D username -w password -b"cn=admin,dc=ivhdev,dc=local" -s sub "(objectClass=*)" "givenName=username*"
ldap_bind: Invalid DN syntax (34)
    additional info: invalid DN
```

Please suggest/correct me, if am passing the right info in DN syntax. I am unable to validate the user credentials with their name and password.

Answer (score 23):

The `-D` option takes the *DN* for logging in to your LDAP server.

The `-b` option takes the search *base* in your LDAP tree where you want to search for the user's given name.

So, your `ldapsearch` command becomes:

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -h ip -D 'cn=admin,dc=ivhdev,dc=local' -w password -b 'dc=users,dc=local' -s sub '(objectClass=*)' 'givenName=username*'
```

Comment: it worked, how do i validate the user with password is correct using the command.

Comment: If you want to validate the same user's credentials simply replace the admin credentials with the user's credentials un the above command. It should work.

Comment: worked for me but I had to put to all the user info in -D.  example
`CN=Lastname\, Firstname M (username),OU=Integration,OU=Corp Ops Engin_Tech,OU=Corporate,OU=Accounts,OU=SPECTR,DC=corp,DC=companycom,DC=com`

Answer (score 4):

If you use the Apache Directory Studio (http://directory.apache.org/studio/) you can see the actual ldapsearch commands used by the application. Maybe this is useful for anyone.